# How to rotate Compiz desktop cube with both mouse buttons?

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiz, mouse, 15.04

Several years back, when Compiz was a new thing, I had a setup with 3D cube that I can't reproduce now. The cube rotation was (by default, I think) initiated by holding down both mouse buttons simultaneously. It was very handy because I could just click the two buttons and drag the cube, no need for keyboard. Is there a way to configure the same behavior now (using 15.04)?